# Regex remove special characters

Tags: c#, regex

We need a C# function which will remove all special characters from a string.

Also, is it possible to change "George's" to "George" (remove both single quote and character s)?

Comment: At least define "special character"

Comment: you mean: remove all that isn't letter, number or space?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This method will removed everything but letters, numbers and spaces. It will also remove any ' or " followed by the character s.

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
{
    Regex r = new Regex("(?:[^a-z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return r.Replace(input, String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the code. It's working fine. Is it possible to ignore the white space. I want the white space to be there. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ryan, We don't want to remove white spaces from the string. Please let me know how to do it. I marked it as solution. Thanks.

Comment: [^a-z0-9 ] says find any character that is not a to z or 0-9 or space. If you need to exclude additional characters in the future you can add them to that group.

Comment: how to remove also the space? What need to be modified from your regex?

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
{    
    Regex r = new Regex(
                  "(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|(?<=['\"])s)",
                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return r.Replace(input, String.Empty);    
}
```

Ryan's answer is right. Just add `A-Z` as well as many people would need it.

Answer (score 0):

Would help if we knew what a *special* character was.  Here's a function though that will do the trick

```
public bool IsSpecialChar(char c) {
  // Need you to fill this out
}

public string RemoveSpecialChars(string s) {
  var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  foreach (var cur in s) {
    if (!IsSpecialChar(cur)) {
      builder.Append(cur);
    }
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to define a list of characters you want to keep instead of enumerating all others you dont want. For instance, using perlregexes `s/[^A-Za-z0-9]+//g` will remove any non word character (sorry, I'm not familiar with c# regexes :D).

For your other problem, you could define what to remove based on the previous word if you care about certain cases (like only removing `'s` if there is a word before it), otherwise just remove all occurrences of `'s`.

Comment: I think you meant `s/\W+//g` (`tr///` is not regex-powered, and the set of "word characters" includes a lot more than just `[A-Za-z0-9]`).  The C# version would be `Regex.Replace(input, @"\W+", String.Empty)`.

Comment: @Alan Moore you are right, I forget about that =). Regarding word characters, I'm aware of that, I actually thought that's what he wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I threw in that bit about word characters to save us both a scolding from tchrist. :D