# c# comma separated string to list

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, csv

I have seen a bunch of examples of handling comma separated lists using Split(','), for a string like:

```
string csv = "1,2,3,4,a,5";
List<string> parts = csv.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

But what happens, and how would you handle a CSV string like this:

```
string csv = '"a,b","c,d","e","f",g,h,i';
```

I would like to be able to parse the csv string into a list or an array, it is more about knowing the best way to handle the string elements that contain a comma in them, and not have a simple parser like Split to get confused around the extra comma.

Alexei's comment was helpful, but after trying it in my real life example, his solution ran into some snags.. So for extra credit.. This is a more accurate csv string that needs to be parsed.

```
csv = '"name 1" <title 1>, "name, 2" <title 2>, name 3 <title 3>, name 4 <title 4>, name 5, name 6';
```

The values would be split into:

```
"name 1" <title 1>
"name, 2" <title 2> 
name 3 <title 3>
name 4 <title 4> 
name 5
name 6
```

Thank you

Comment: Find a CSV parser on NuGet.

Comment: try CSVHelper: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: What do expect to be the output of your second string?

Comment: by default all answers that parse CSV with Split are wrong but for some reason SO is full of them :[

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to do it. It is the quickest and easiest way. Make sure to add `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to your references. Put the single and double quotes as your special characters and it will strip them out. See this post for details.

[Regex remove special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418279/regex-remove-special-characters)

Comment: Regex is awful for this. It's slow relative to a dedicated parser, and still vulnerable a number of edge cases. It's so easy to just add a real csv parser from Nuget, or if you don't like the dependency there are a number of single *.cs file options you can find and include with your project.

Comment: With all due respect @Joel Coehoorn there are typically more than one way to skin the cat. I wouldnt say regex is awful, it depends on the requirements and application and that is up the the op to decide. Our job is to present the possibilities and regex is certainly a viable solution that works. While it can have a performance impact, that impact can be negligible, again depending on the op's application. It does have some pros too that can outweigh the cons.

Comment: For the sake of helping the op, here is an article. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations/ I am not going to say my way is the best way, it is just another way. Read the articles and try them out to see what is best for you and your application. Regex can have a performance hit but it may be so small, it doesnt affect you

Comment: Quotes aren't special characters, they are text delimiters used when the cell contains separators. While regular expressions can be used to parse CSVs, this answer will only mangle the data

Comment: I found this RegEx works for my example `([^>]+>)[, ]{0,2}|([^^]+)[, ]{2}|([^^]+)[, ]{0}` @MichaelBedford

Comment: In my real data set I found I only needed `([^>]+>)[, ]{0,2}` the other two options in the previous RegEx solved the extended example above.

Answer (score 0):

Plain C# solution for the second string. It assumes it is a valid CSV, with no blanks between the tokens. I do not think it is the fastest, but it should be enough for reasonable sized arrays (~MB). Complexity is `O(n)`:

```
private static void AddToBuilder(IList<string> parts, StringBuilder sb)
{
    if (sb.Length > 0)
        parts.Add(sb.ToString());

    sb.Clear();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string csv = "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"e\",\"f\",g,h,i";
    var parts = new List<string>();
    bool innerString = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in csv)
    {
        if (c == '\"')
        {
            if (innerString)
                AddToBuilder(parts, sb);

            innerString = !innerString;
            continue;
        }

        if (c == ',' && !innerString)
        {
            AddToBuilder(parts, sb);
            continue;
        }

        sb.Append(c);
    }

    AddToBuilder(parts, sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance a third party CSV parser is not an option, another alternative is [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) (needs Reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`):

```
string CSV = "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"e\",\"f\",g,h,i";
string[] fields;

using (var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(CSV))  
using (var tfp = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(sr)) {
    tfp.SetDelimiters(",");
    fields = tfp.ReadFields();
}
```

It also handles values that contain properly escaped quotes.

Comment: Good suggestion, you need to add References -> Assemblies -> Framework -> Microsoft.VisualBasic for this to work for C#. Unfortunately it did not work on my data set to solve my problem, but may help others.